# UWP's Windows.Devices.Perception sample app

Tags: c#, uwp

I can't seem to find any samples demonstrating the use of the `Windows.Devices.Perception` APIs. There doesn't seem to be one in the UWP SDK samples. Also, information is scarce other than the Microsoft API doc.

Is this API deprecated or still active? 
I am trying to work out how to use the API.

Is this the recommended way to get the depth/infra frames or is the recommended way using the `Windows.Media.Capture` APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Ok after closer look at the Microsoft API docs for this namespace. I can see it is tagged as Deprecated. So I guess the Windows.Media.Capture is the correct way to grab the infra frames now.